# How do I figure out which /dev is a USB flash drive?

Tags: linux, usb

I want to mount a USB drive, two of them and I need two different mount points. Unfortunately, the Linux kernel underwent a name change and I can't figure out which `/dev` location is the right one. Is there a way to look through `dmesg` or `/proc` or somewhere else to find out which device node is a USB drive.

(I'm using ArchLinux if that helps any...`/dev/sda` is the first hard drive, `/dev/sr0` is a dvd drive, etc.)

*edit: The USB drive is connected to a USB hub. I looked through `dmesg` and it says the hub was connected and it scanned for the 3 devices connected to it. Still can't see where my USB drive is though.*

Comment: Can't see it? Maybe wait for a bit. Or try another USB port. See what differences there is in 'lsusb'

Comment: Might want to rephrase the question somewhat - not all usb devices are disks, after all.

Comment: The `df` command shows you where it was mounted

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Easiest way: Look at the output of `dmesg` after connecting the USB device.  It should show you what `/dev` node was assigned to it.

Comment: `dmesg` works great, but I have a case where `dmesg` does not show the `/dev` node: `[421963.864281] usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd` What does this mean? How can I mount this device? The device shows up on `lsusb`...

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. There was a kernel update since my last reboot that was causing this problem. After a reboot, my usb mounts just fine. Hopefully this helps someone!

Answer (score 63):

All of these are good suggestions, but the quickest and least verbose method is to just type the following in the terminal:

```
mount
```

which will give a list of all the mounted devices (this assumes the USB drive is mounted, which is usually the case with modern Linux distros).

Comment: No, it doesn't magically mount your device. You have to specify it with `mount /dev/id /mount/point`, so that doesn't work.

Comment: My answer addresses the user's question 'Is there a way to look through dmesg or /proc or somewhere else to find out which device node is a USB drive.', and is not intended to provide guidance on the practicality of mounting a drive under Linux.

Comment: This answer solved an almost identical question for me.

Comment: I think automount behavior depends alot on the distro type.

Comment: `df` too, i suppose.

Answer (score 57):

As long as you are running [udev](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev), you can do this easily by referencing /dev/disk/by-id/usb-*manufacturername*_*serialnumber*.  These appear as symbolic links which you can either directly reference within your fstab, or which you can dereference using **readlink -e** to determine the associated block device.

Here's a real world example.  On my machine, I have 3 USB hard drives connected.  These each show up in /dev/disk/by-id with unique serial numbers (although they share a common manufacturer string).  I have created symbolic links to each of these three unique entries, and can now quickly determine which drive is which (and which device is associated with each drive) by running **readlink -e *linkname***.  For example, running **readlink -e /root/disk2** on my machine currently displays "**/dev/sde**", while **readlink -e /root/disk3** produces no output whatsoever.

Comment: Short and simply: `for devlink in /dev/disk/by-id/usb*; do readlink -f ${devlink}; done`

Comment: ^ above comment should be an answer

Comment: Attaching my Crucial SATA SSD with a USB SATA adapter, it does not appear as `/dev/disk/by-id/usb-...`, but as `/dev/disk/by-id/ata-...` ... and my USB-connected *Seagate Expansion Desk* appears as `/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-...`.

Answer (score 28):

Try the command `udevinfo -q all -n /dev/sda`, where `/dev/sda` is the path to your disk. This gives you a boatload of info about the disk you're looking at - there's an entry that tells you about the bus it's connected to.

This of course saves you from having to grep through dmesg and/or logs.

**Update**

```
udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/sda
```

From at least  Jul 2010 <sup>[[1](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2010/07/msg01134.html)]</sup> `udevinfo` was substituted in Debian (and derived) by `udevadm info` with a little transient with which there were symlinks soon deprecated and removed (you can still found them in old not updated machine). Always from [[1](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2010/07/msg01134.html)] we can read:

> In udev 117, `udevadm` was introduced and `udevinfo` and other programs turned into compatibility symlinks.  The symlinks were deprecated in *udev 128* and removed for good in *udev 147*.

Comment: In Debian, `udevinfo` is renamed `udevadm`.

Comment: On Ubuntu, the command seems to be "udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/sda"

Comment: I suppose they renamed the command at some point - when I wrote the answer (ages ago) the command worked on the ubuntu system that I posted it from ;)

Comment: Command works still in ubuntu, `udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/ttyUSB1`

Comment: `udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/ttyUSB` in Fedora too.

Answer (score 24):

the simplest method to see what's going on is just typing (as root of course):

```
blkid -c /dev/null
```

this gives you a complete overview about all block devices even if not mounted

Comment: Not all distro have this. Which were you using?

Comment: This outputs nothing on my Raspbian distro.

Comment: **Command not found: blkid**

Comment: No output from this command on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

And just analyse the result.

Comment: [fdisk man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk) "If no devices are given, those mentioned in /proc/partitions (if that exists) are used."  Running fdisk may not be an option...  Based on one Debian system that I know doesn't have it installed, my guess is that some GPT systems might not install the unneeded software.  Still, checking /proc/partitions ought to be an option.

Comment: This was the only option that worked fine for me. I am sorry if it didn't work for you!

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/usb*
```

Under the default udev rules, that will show you most usb devices and it will show you the symlink to their block-device name on the system.

If that doesn't work, look at `/dev/disk/by-id/` directly.

Answer (score 12):

`/dev/disk/by-*` is the easiest way in this case, if for some reason you want to make life more interesting you can use HAL.

To list all devices you use:

```
hal-device
```

To get a specific property you use (this will return `/dev/sd*` on a USB storage device):

```
hal-get-property --udi $UDI --key block.device
```

There is also:

```
hal-find-by-capability
hal-find-by-property
```

If you want to make it even more complicated you can relatively easy write yourself a [HAL based auto mounter](http://redclay.altervista.org/wiki/doku.php?id=projects%3Ahal-automount), which can be quite handy if you want to automate things completly.

And just for completeness there are also:

```
lsusb -v
lshw
```

Which provides some general information about USB and your hardware in general.

Comment: /dev/disk/by-id/*usb* is very helpful.

Comment: /dev/disk/by-label ftw. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

For USB devices you can simply do

```bsh
REMOVABLE_DRIVES=""
for _device in /sys/block/*/device; do
    if echo $(readlink -f "$_device")|egrep -q "usb"; then
        _disk=$(echo "$_device" | cut -f4 -d/)
        REMOVABLE_DRIVES="$REMOVABLE_DRIVES $_disk"
    fi
done
echo Removable drives found: "$REMOVABLE_DRIVES"
```

Comment: +1. Simple and concise script to do the task automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the tree under `/dev/disk`. It lists disks and their partitions (file systems) by various schemes.

Answer (score 2):

/var/log/message if dmesg no longer has the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you unplug the USB drive and plug it back in, you should see it initialize from the kernel (dmesg)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the excellent answer from stormlash and with a dependency on udev to populate the "/dev/disk/by-id/usb" device tree, you could define a predicate (Bash) as follows:

```bsh
is_usb_device() {
    local device_path=$1        # such as /dev/sdc
    for devlink in /dev/disk/by-id/usb*; do
        if [ "$(readlink -f "$devlink")" = "$device_path" ]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}
```

And then use it:

```bsh
if is_usb_device "/dev/sdg"; then
    echo "/dev/sdg is a usb device"
else
    echo "/dev/sdg is not a usb device"
fi
```