# How to mount 20 year old IDE Drive in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount

I asked a question similar to this one about an hour ago but my account got messed up somehow and it wont let me comment anymore :p

Anyways, I have a 20 year old IDE Conner Hard Disk attached to a live disc parted magic os using a usb connector. When I try to mount the disk it says:

```
udevil: error 64: unable to determine device fstype
```

What should I do?

Comment: You are correct that reformatting it will erase everything.  If the data is that important, then you may want to consider taking the drive to a data recovery specialist company.

Comment: Does anything show up in Disk Management? Do you know what version of Windows it was from? Try hooking it up to a Mac?

Comment: windows disk management tells me to initialize the disk (but doing so would result in total data loss)

Comment: Boot a live linux disk that can read old FAT tables (Fat16 perhaps?) and then copy it to another drive

Comment: Okay, whats a good linux distro to use for this? (preferably something i can download in less than 10 mins)

Comment: Maybe Knoppix. Also, use @userName if you want someone to know you replied to them

Comment: @miken32 The HDD is from a Toshiba Satellite T1900. Official Toshiba site says it was released in 1993 (before windows 95 obviously lmao) it's safe to assume it had windows 3.1 on it

Comment: @Ramhound It was a laptop used for post grad projects back in the 90s the computer was long lost until just yesterday. Your guess is as good as mine as to what file system it has

Comment: Try loading DOS onto a virtual machine? Or, get yourself another ancient laptop. I've got a Satellite Pro T400 sitting in my closet, I bet I'm not the only one.

Comment: Should be noted that GParted sees the drive as a 2TB disk for some reason

Comment: If it is really that old, it might be minix. Not sure nowadays kernel still carry compatibility for that fs.

Comment: well the hard drive was from an old Toshiba Satellite T1900 which i can only assume had DOS or even Windows 3.1 on it

Comment: Tried hooking it up to a PC directly, not using USB? You can get 2.5 to 3.5 IDE adapters. Pins are all the same, so it's just a passive adapter.

Answer (score 5):

You can try directly accessing the drive at the block level under Linux and extract an image of the drive into a file (you must be logged in as root to do this):

```
dd if=<drive device file> of=<desired image file location> bs=512
```

You can then analyze the disk image using software tools. If that doesn't work, your only other choice is to send the drive in to a professional data recovery service.

Comment: Can i do this with Ultimate Boot CD?

Comment: Yes, you can. `dd` is part of the GNU Core Utilities, so it's in virtually all Linux distros. Be sure to boot into Linux (use the Parted Magic option; Parted Magic is a Linux distribution designed specifically for partitioning drives) and mount your main hard drive so that you can write the image to it. In case you need help, have you worked with the Linux command line before?

Comment: i gotta burn a new ubcd and ill give it a go

Comment: To determine which device file in `/dev` is the old hard drive (which you've stated is connected to USB), see this question: [How do I figure out which /dev is a USB flash drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/361885/how-do-i-figure-out-which-dev-is-a-usb-flash-drive)

Comment: Okay i tired this command and it says: 0+0 records in 0+0 records out 0 bytes copied.... Anything else i can try?

Comment: Apparently, the capacity of the hard drive as presented by the operating system is zero, which likely means that the hard drive controller can't communicate with the actual media (disk platters, read/write head). You'll need to send the hard drive in to a data recovery service.

Comment: @DragonLord is there anyway i can test to be 100% sure?

Comment: Try opening Disk Management (the Windows partitioning utility) and see if the drive has a zero or non-zero capacity. If it is zero, you'll need to send it in.

Comment: @DragonLord windows wont let me view the drive until i "initialize" it :p

Answer (score 0):

You might search the internet for some specialized software to be able to read and allow you access to the data on the drive. Just because windows is asking you to format it doesn't necessarily mean the data still isn't there.

Buy yeah, don't format It

Comment: ive tried about a half a dozen data recovery programs and they all do is one of 3 things: 1. Shows drive but says it has 0bytes and then refuses to check the drive 2.Checks the drive but stops immediately with no results. 3. the program crashes

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the disk might be old enough that on the original machine you had to enter all its parameters by hand into a table in the BIOS (number of sectors, cylinders, platters, heads etc). If so, all the relevant information would be printed on the disk label, which is hopefully still readable.

This doesn't help much; I don't know how to translate that disk attachment strategy to modern software, but if you can find a contemporary PC (with BIOS that doesn't just assume it can auto-detect disks, but has the disk parameter table in its setup menu) that ought to be able to read the disk.

Or perhaps this answer may trigger a better one from someone who DOES remember how to access old disks via newer software.

Comment: i have all of that information for this specific drive, how would i input all that into my bios?

Comment: You would need a BIOS old enough to have a "disk parameters" page in the BIOS setup menu.